# Extracting two different JSON strings from one text file into an JSON array

Tags: json, groovy

I am trying to read two different JSON objects from one text file into a JSON array but I am able to extract just the first string but not the second:

```
    class CreateFinalResponse {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String fileContents = new File('C:\\Users\\Input\\intermediateResponse.txt').getText('UTF-8')
        println(fileContents);
        println("*************************************************")
        def inputJSON = new JsonSlurper().parseText(fileContents)
        inputJSON.each{ println it }
    }
}
```

I get the following response for the above code :

```
    {
    "employeeId": {
        "0": "10999999",
        "1": "10999999",
        "2": "10999999",
        "3": "10999999",
        "4": "10999999",
        "5": "10999999",
        "6": "10999999",
        "7": "10999999",
        "8": "10999999",
        "9": "10999999",
        "10": "10999999",
        "11": "10999999",
        "12": "10999999",
        "13": "10999999",
        "14": "10999999",
        "15": "10999999",
        "16": "10999999",
        "17": "10999999",
        "18": "10999999",
        "19": "10999999"
    }
}

    {
        "response": {
            "ExecuteResult": "false",
            "outputvalue1": "311",
            "outputvalue2": "8fc3b98c342b9898c4adde51ca8b951c0de1b53930d5512a9c410212bb3a1f956fb51fe4f3c2355951ee79f4bab6eda39a71937f6983315be4dd334777135584",
            "outputvalue3": "Partial Upload successful, a few employee's failed",
            "message": "[Response :0:500:ex\":0,\"httpCode\":200,\"inlineResults\":null}]]"
        }
    }
    *************************************************
    employeeId={0=10999999, 1=10999999, 2=10999999, 3=10999999, 4=10999999, 5=10999999, 6=10999999, 7=10999999, 8=10999999, 9=10999999, 10=10999999, 11=10999999, 12=10999999, 13=10999999, 14=10999999, 15=10999999, 16=10999999, 17=10999999, 18=10999999, 19=10999999}
```

How can I extract both these JSON's into an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String fileContents = new File('C:\\Users\\Input\\intermediateResponse.txt').getText('UTF-8')    
def splited = fileContents.split("\n\n")
def listOfJSONs = []
splited.each{
    listOfJSONs << new JsonSlurper().parseText(it)
}
listOfJSONs.each{ println it }
```